# How to understand if page is loaded as iframe (external site) using javascript?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I'm trying to find a reliable solution to determine if my page was loaded in iframe on external site using javascript.

If iframe src located on the same domain it's preaty easy: you can use if (window.frameElement) or if (window.location !== window.parent.location) but if iframe src is not on the same domain all modern browsers throw exception when accessing parent and even comparing it with null.

I'm totally lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in the Coding Horror entry: [We Done Been Framed](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/06/we-done-been-framed.html).  Offers an interesting technical discussion on this topic, including solutions, and frame-busting-busting.

Comment: Nice article. The code from that article that the OP may want to try is: if (parent.frames.length > 0) {
    top.location.replace(document.location);
}   Though the point of the article is that it is impossible to 100% bust frames from JavaScript, and the best you can do is notify users of a frame from server side code.

Comment: So... what you're saying is my answer is informative in more ways than one for the asker ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your validation (window.location !== window.parent.location / window.frameElement) in try-catch statement which you can use to handle the exception yourself.

Comment: Well it doesn't work - at least in Firefox 3.6.12. Code doesn't throw exception.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try a function with the following

var element = window.parent.document
if (element) return "Is in a parent window" else "is not in a parent window";