# Checking if my page is embedded in an iframe

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, iframe

I would like to test if my page (php) is embedded in an iframe or not, in order to implement a different behaviour. Any idea how to test this. I'm also using jQuery if it helps.

**Addition :**
I'm especially interested if there would be a method to test this on the server rather than in the client with Javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect iFrame embedding in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925039/detect-iframe-embedding-in-javascript)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to understand if page is loaded as iframe (external site) using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179795/how-to-understand-if-page-is-loaded-as-iframe-external-site-using-javascript)

Comment: not real duplicates, because I'd like to test this on server preferably!

Comment: So why do you tag your question with JavaScript and jQuery then? It is not possible at the server side. But even then it would be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896623/how-to-prevent-my-site-page-to-be-loaded-via-3rd-party-site-frame-of-iframe

Comment: @Felix because it wasn't very clear in my mind.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use JavaScript, I think something like the following should work:

```
if (top != self) {
    // you're in an iframe, or similar.
}
```

[Link to original, meyerweb, article](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2009/04/14/digging-in-the-mud/).

---

**Edited** with regard to the question's update:

> **Addition** : I'm especially interested if there would be a method to test this on the server rather than in the client with Javascript

This can't be 'checked' on the server side, but, you *could* use the [`X-Frame-Options` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/the_x-frame-options_response_header), there are two options:

1. `DENY`: prevents the resource being framed anywhere (assuming the browser supports the X-Frame-Options header, anyway), or
2. `SAMEORIGIN`: which allows framing of the resource only by pages from the same-domain, much like JavaScript's same-origin policy.

To use this, you'd need to configure your server to send the relevant header; though specific advice for that can't be given without knowing what server you're running; though the linked article at the [Mozilla Developer Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/the_x-frame-options_response_header) does show the Apache option.

Answer (score 4):

maybe:

```
var isInIFrame = (window.location != window.parent.location) ? true : false;
```

Comment: What do you need `? true : false` for?

Comment: Maybe he doesn't know that he can set a value like this `var isInIFrame = (window.location != window.parent.location);` anyway, its the samething

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there is a specific JQueryway but in vanilla javascript you can simply;

```
if (top != self)
  alert("framed!")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function InFrame()
{

  if (top.location != location) {
  //Do whatever you need- your site is in an iframe.

  //This will redirect to your site if you need to
  //top.location.href = document.location.href ;
  //
  }
}
</script>
```